# Should i use another database for my web application?

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, multiple-databases, real-time-data

I'm developing a web application using Node.js for backend(express) and React.js for frontend. I'm using PostgreSQL as database for almost every data storage. But now, i will add a real time chatting system and also some real time updates. I heard MongoDB is a good as a real time chatting database. So should i use two database for my web application? If not, what are the best alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use 2 databases. This will give you much more control over your data and in case of an issue in either of the applications, it will not affect the other. It will also be effective when handling maintenance.

Comment: But i only working on one application, you said like chatting system and my website seperate applications, why ?
also can you explain downsides of using two database in one application?